# Altair Chart "reads" more information from TimeStamps than it should

Tags: python, altair

everyone

I have a DataFrame that looks like the following (I got this by doing `df.to_dict()`):

```
{'end_datum': {48: Timestamp('2020-09-25 00:00:00'),
  96: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'),
  77: Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00'),
  51: Timestamp('2020-09-25 00:00:00'),
  95: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00')},
 'type': {48: 'Frist Gericht',
  96: 'Frist Gericht',
  77: 'Berufungsfrist',
  51: 'Frist Gericht',
  95: 'Frist Gericht'},
 'motorenbezeichnung': {48: 'EA 189',
  96: 'EA 288',
  77: 'OM 642',
  51: 'OM 651',
  95: 'EA 189'},
 'size': {48: 30, 96: 9, 77: 1, 51: 8, 95: 54}}
```

I've plotted one Altair Chart with following code:

```
alt.Chart(pv_clean).mark_bar().encode(
    x= "end_datum:T",
    y="size:Q",
    color = "motorenbezeichnung:N").properties(width=1000)
```

and I got the following output:

[image: chart_with_weird_x_axis]

The labels along the X axis contain to much information. I've tried using altair's `transform_timeunit()`,

```
alt.Chart(pv_clean).mark_bar().encode(
    y= "date(end_datum:T)",
    x="size:Q",
    color = "motorenbezeichnung:N").properties(width=1000)
```

but than the Chart goes blank:

[image: blank_chart]

The funny thing is that if I change the dates from the x to the y axis,

```
alt.Chart(pv_clean).mark_bar().encode(
    y= "end_datum:T",
    x="size:Q",
    color = "motorenbezeichnung:N").properties(width=1000)
```

the dates are parsed in a way that makes more sense:
[image: Sensible_dates_displayed_on_y_axis]

Could anyone please explain me the following:

1. How can I get the day of the month and the month to be displayed in the X axis?
2. Why dates are interpreted differently in the x and the y axis in Altair charts?
3. Why does the Chart goes blank, when I try to transforme the time unit?

I'm using jupyter lab version 2.2.6 and Altair version 4.1.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default number of ticks on the x axis is more than you would like.

One convenient way to address this is to set the minimum space between ticks to what you would like to see; for temporal axes, the ticks are spaced in milliseconds, so using

```
x=alt.X("end_datum:T", axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1000*60*60*24))
```

makes things look a bit better.

Here's a full example, using the data you provided:

```
alt.Chart(pv_clean).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X("end_datum:T", axis=alt.Axis(tickMinStep=1000*60*60*24)),
    y="size:Q",
    color = "motorenbezeichnung:N"
).properties(width=1000)
```

[image]

Note that your chart 2 doesn't work because you wrote `y= "date(end_datum:T)"` instead of `y= "date(end_datum):T"`, and Chart 3 does work because the y-axis spans fewer pixels which leads to fewer default ticks.